# Dump whole database from Google App Engine with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to dump the WHOLE database from Google App Engine.  However, I got an 'AttributeError'.

**AttributeError: type object AddressBook has no attribute cursor**

Does anyone know how to dump the whole database from Google App Engine?

```
gql_string = "SELECT * FROM AddressBook"
q = ndb.gql(gql_string)

csv_output = "id,name,addr,cellphone"

cursor = memcache.get('cursor')
if cursor:
    AddressBook.with_cursor(start_cursor=cursor)
while cursor:
    cursor = memcache.get('cursor')
    if cursor:
        AddressBook.with_cursor(start_cursor=cursor)

    for p in q:
        csv_output += (p.id + "," + p.name + "," + p.addr + "," + p.cellphone + "\n")

    cursor = AddressBook.cursor()
    memcache.set('cursor', cursor)
```

Comment: As far as I know `with_cursor` is applied to a query `q` in your case

Comment: I tried, but still get `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute cursor`

Comment: It seems that you exausted the results, if what you want is to incrementally fetch the results, you will need to restructure your code to fetch the cursor, fetch some results, get the cursor from the query, then repeat later.